# Loading very large table using SSIS 2005

Tags: ssis, load

I have a question.I'm working on loading a Very large table having existing data of the order of 150 million records which will keep on growing by adding 1 million records on a daily basis.Few days back the ETL started failing even after running for 24 hrs. In the DFT, we have source query pulling 1 million records which is LOOKed UP against the Destination table having 150 million records to check for new records. It is failing as the LOOKUP cannot hold data for 150 million records. I have tried changing the LOOKUP to Merge Join without success. Can you please suggest alternative designs to load the data in the large table successfully. Moreover, there is no way I can reduce the size of destination table. I  already have indexes on all required columns. Hope I'm clear in explaining the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can try table partitioning to import a large amount of data. Take a look [here](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Switching_Partitions_-_Example) for an example. Another [link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/partitioned-tables-in-sql-server-2005/) that might be useful. Also, check msdn for more information about creating and maintaining partitioned tables.

Comment: But how will i check for the new records if i use partitioning on Target table?

Comment: Your question is quite broad to give an exact answer. I'd suggest creating a temporary table that keeps records which could be possible duplicates of new data (depends on the nature of data you may or may not use partitioning for that purpose), then merge it with new data, and finally switch partition.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies but i do not have any specific scenario with which i can create a temp table with possible hit targets.I'm thinking about splitting the target table into parts with T-SQL query and use it to join with source query to find possible newer records which would be joined with the various parts one by one to get to the actual new records.this is what i can think of right now.Will try that at work tomorrow, just came to mind now.Would appreciate a lot if you can suggest any better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the journey into two.

Create a new data flow task (or separate package) to stage your source table "as is" in an environment close to your target database

Alter your existing data flow task to query across both your staged table and the target table to pull out only new (and changed?) records and process these accordingly within SSIS.  This should eliminate the need to have the expensive look-up performing a round trip to the database per record

Comment: Doesn't help as the databases are on same machine but still data volumes are very large for LOOKUPs or JOINs.

Comment: This thread might help you... [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/3c6fe6cc-3799-4375-955a-946e960ea13d/)

Comment: That's a Nice thread but doesn't solve my problem.i can't really think of any other way to break the DFT into parts other than the one i already mentioned.